# Добавление полей с jQuery на динамической форме Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, forms

Задача состоит в следующем: есть динамическая форма, в которой добавляются/удаляются некоторые поля. Необходимо, чтобы к каждому добавляемому полю был применен Autocomplete с указанным массивом. Но Autocomplete добавляется только к первому полю. Из сгенерированного html понял, что не прописывается функция jQuery().autocomplete для динамически добавляемых полей. Собственно вопрос: как прописать эти функции в коде?

Часть кода view с динамическими блоками

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>Ответственные</h4></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
                    'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
                    'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
                    'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
                    'limit' => 10, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
                    'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
                    'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
                    'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
                    'model' => $modelResponsible[0],
                    'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
                    'formFields' => [
                        'people_id',
                    ],
                ]); ?>

                <div class="container-items"><!-- widgetContainer -->
                    <?php foreach ($modelResponsible as $i => $modelResponsibleOne): ?>
                        <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Ответственный</h3>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                                    <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <?php
                                // necessary for update action.
                                if (! $modelResponsibleOne->isNewRecord) {
                                    echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelResponsibleOne, "[{$i}]id");
                                }
                                ?>

                                <?php
                                echo $form->field($modelResponsibleOne, "[{$i}]people_id")->widget(
                                    \yii\jui\AutoComplete::className(), [
                                    'clientOptions' => [
                                        'source' => $model->people_arr,
                                    ],
                                    'options'=>[
                                        'class'=>'form-control',
                                    ]
                                ])->label('ФИО');

                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
                <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Спасибо

Comment: Логично, что не добавляется. Вы сформировали документ. К нему применился `jQuery.autocomplete()` после чего вы в документ, скажем, через `AJAX` догрузили еще полей. Откуда об этом узнает `jQuery.autocomplete()`? Очевидно, что после добавления в документ новых полей нужно заново вызвать метод инициализации `jQuery.autocomplete()`, чтобы он заново оббежал весь документ и навесил на все поля свой обработчик.

Comment: @user413219, это я понял но вопрос как именно это сделать? Я так понял добавить поле вместе с автокомплитом нельзя

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699307/jquery-ui-autocomplete-refresh-data